# Messenger Bot generic template buttons and subtitle not showing in android app

Tags: node.js, chatbot, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, messenger

I am in middle of building a messenger chat-bot which was working fine but now the buttons and subtitle are not showing in my android phone (I have Xiaomi Poco F1). I have not tested it with any ios device. But it seems to work just fine in browser. I am not able to figure out if this an issue from my side or some bug in messenger app.

Chrome Messenger Image

[image]

Android Messenger App Image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the App. I re-installed it after clearing cache and data. Now everything is working fine.